# React Js Updating a value inside a array with onChange to a child component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components

I have a list with opening_hours that I map inside my render function. I map them to a child component. I want to change the value of each object inside my parent state when the child component state is changed. Only problem is that my values don't change in the child component nor the parent state. I have passed the onChange method to each child component, but the problem lies in my onChange function in the parent state.

I have tried to pass the onChange to my child component and update the state with [e.target.name] : e.target.value. But that didn't work. So I tried to copy the arrayList and update the state based on the index of the mapped arrayList. That also didn't work.

```
    handleOnChange =  (index) => {
        let newData = [...this.state.opening_hours];
        this.setState(
            newData.map((barbershop, j) => {
                if (j === index) {
                    return barbershop;
                    console.log(barbershop)
                }
            return {
                newData,
            };
        }));
        console.log(newData)
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="container mb-2">
                    <h4>Opening hours </h4>
                    <Form>
                        {this.state.opening_hours.map((barbershop, index) => (
                            <Day
                                key={barbershop.id}
                                day={barbershop.day}
                                open_time={barbershop.open_time}
                                close_time={barbershop.close_time}
                                index = {index}
                                onChange={() => this.handleOnChange(index)}/>
                        ))}
                    </Form>


                    <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit} variant="primary" type="submit">
                        Update opening hours
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

My child component looks like this

```
class Day extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            day: this.props.day,
            open_time: this.props.open_time,
            close_time: this.props.close_time,
        };
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    handleChange = () => {
        this.props.onChange(this.props.index)
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <Form.Group as={Row}>
                <Form.Label column sm="3">
                    {ENUM[this.state.day]}
                </Form.Label>
                <Col sm="3">
                    <Form.Control
                        name="open_time"
                        value={this.state.open_time}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        type="time"
                        min="08:00"
                        max="24:00"/>
                </Col>
                <Col sm="3">
                    <Form.Control
                        name="close_time"
                        value={this.state.close_time}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        type="time"
                        min="08:00"
                        max="24:00"/>
                </Col>
            </Form.Group>
        );
    }
}
```

> EDIT:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have done some investigation, I believe the problem is that you are not returning data back to the consumer.

Here is what I think, the solution is:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";

class UI extends Component {
  handleOnChange = ({ index, ...newHours }) => {
    // update array item
    const opening_hours = this.state.opening_hours.map((item, i) => {
      const newData = i === index ? newHours : {};

      return {
        ...item,
        ...newData
      };
    });

    // update item in opening_hours => state
    this.setState({ opening_hours });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container mb-2">
        <h4>Opening hours</h4>

        <Form>
          {this.state.opening_hours.map(({ id, ...barbershop }, index) => (
            <Day
              key={id}
              {...barbershop}
              {...{ index }}
              onChange={this.handleOnChange}
            />
          ))}
        </Form>

        <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit} variant="primary" type="submit">
          Update opening hours
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Day = ({ day, onChange, index, ...props }) => {
  const [open_time, setOpenTime] = useState(props.open_time);
  const [close_time, setCloseTime] = useState(props.close_time);

  useEffect(() => {
    onChange({ index, open_time, close_time });
  }, [open_time, close_time, onChange, index]);

  const sharedProps = {
    type: "time",
    min: "08:00",
    max: "24:00"
  };

  return (
    <Form.Group as={Row}>
      <Form.Label column sm="3">
        {ENUM[day]}
      </Form.Label>

      <Col sm="3">
        <Form.Control
          {...sharedProps}
          name="open_time"
          value={open_time}
          onChange={({ target }) => setOpenTime(target.value)}
        />
      </Col>

      <Col sm="3">
        <Form.Control
          {...sharedProps}
          name="close_time"
          value={close_time}
          onChange={({ target }) => setCloseTime(target.value)}
        />
      </Col>
    </Form.Group>
  );
};
```

Comment: When I change the open_time and close_time of a certain day it changes it for every day. Sometimes it changes for an other day. It's really random I have tried it with console.log. How is this possible?

Comment: Can you try `i === index`

Comment: YES! IT FINALLY WORKED. Could you please explain how it works? And why it differs from mine. I really want to learn from my mistakes and am grateful that you helped me.

Comment: Sure, the premise behind the code is that your receiving data when a component updates. I returned index for the array item location and data required. The map is very simple is loops over each item in your array, if the map() index matches the index from the handler then it takes the data and spreads it over the existing data therefor updating the props without changing array order.

Comment: The bug was that the expression. Is was evaluating if the index was not handler index. So every other item except the one we want was being updated. Does this help clarify things?

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. But why do you use ''useState(props.open_time), useEffect,and setOpenTime/setCloseTime. Could you maybe explain that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194304/discussion-between-tony-stark-and-neil).

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a function that calls `this.handleChange(index)`, but you should really be passing that method as a prop to your `<Day />` component and call it in there. You're already passing in the `index` (although I would use `barbershop.id` instead)

So in your parent component, I would do this instead:

```
<Day 
  key={barbershop.id}
  day={barbershop.day}
  open_time={barbershop.open_time}
  close_time={barbershop.close_time}
  index = {barbershop.id}
  handleChange={this.handleOnChange}
/>
```

Then in your `this.handleChange` method in the parent component, if you're just trying to get `this.state.opening_hours` for a specific barbershop, I would do something like this instead:

```
handleChange = (id) => {
  this.setState(() => ({
    opening_hours: this.state.opening_hours.filter((barbershop) => { 
      return barbershop.id === id;
    })
  }))
}
```

Comment: My whole array dissappears when I try this. How is that possible?

Comment: I have only one problem left. Every time I change the value it creates a new object in my array without changing the values of specific value in the array. This is my current code: I have used the spread operator like this, but it says now "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." How can I fix that? This is how I have the code right now: handleOnChange = (id) => { this.setState(previousState => ({ opening_hours: [...previousState.opening_hours, this.state.opening_hours.filter((barbershop) => { return barbershop.id === id; }) ]})) }

Comment: You can do something like this then: 
`this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  opening_hours: this.state.opening_hours.filter((barbershop) => { return barbershop.id === id; })
}))
`

Comment: @Jbonez87 I have used your new solution, but it removes the whole array still.

Comment: @TonyStark what are you trying to do to this array? are you trying to filter out all the barbershops that don't match that id and just return that barbershop? From your original code, that's what it looked like you were trying to do. Can you also share what values `this.state.opening_hours` starts with when the parent component mounts?

Comment: @Jbonez87 I have added an image on my original post. That is what is within my array. What I want to do is when you change open_time and close_time in the child state that it is also updates in the parent state array.

Comment: .filter() is not a valid solution, as I quickly figured out. As it returns a new array of the item you want changed but looses the index order and other sibling obj data. I settled on using .map()